# How can I get a list of methods that are originally *defined* in a class in php?

Tags: php, class, methods

I'm trying to get a list of methods that were actually defined in a definition for a given class (not just inherited from another class). For example:

```
class A
{   function bob()
    {
    }
}
class B extends A
{   function rainbrew()
    {
    }

}
class C extends B
{   function bob()
    {
    }
}

echo print_r(get_defined_class_methods("A"), true)."<br>\n";
echo print_r(get_defined_class_methods("B"), true)."<br>\n";
echo print_r(get_defined_class_methods("C"), true)."<br>\n";
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
array([0]=>bob)
array([0]=>rainbrew)
array([0]=>bob)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](http://php.net/reflection) for this:

```
$reflectA = new ReflectionClass('A');
print_r($reflectA->getMethods());
```

This will actually give you an array of ReflectionMethod objects, but you can easily extrapolate what you need from there.  ReflectionMethods provide a `getDeclaringClass()` function for this, so you can find which functions were declared in which class:

```
$reflectC = new ReflectionClass('C');
$methods = $reflectC->getMethods();
$classOnlyMethods = array();
foreach($methods as $m) {
    if ($m->getDeclaringClass()->name == 'C') {
        $classOnlyMethods[] = $m->name;
    }
}
print_r($classOnlyMethods);
```

This will give:

```
Array ( [0] => bob )
```

So, as a final solution, try this:

```
function get_defined_class_methods($className)
{
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $methods = $reflect->getMethods();
    $classOnlyMethods = array();
    foreach($methods as $m) {
        if ($m->getDeclaringClass()->name == $className) {
            $classOnlyMethods[] = $m->name;
        }
    }
    return $classOnlyMethods;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like you want to use [get_class_methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)

```
<?php

class myclass {
    // constructor
    function myclass()
    {
        return(true);
    }

    // method 1
    function myfunc1()
    {
        return(true);
    }

    // method 2
    function myfunc2()
    {
        return(true);
    }
}

$class_methods = get_class_methods('myclass');
// or
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new myclass());

foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {
    echo "$method_name\n";
}

?>
```

> The above example will output:
>
> myclass myfunc1 myfunc2